# Adding a column to all document library created in sharepoint using Remote event receiver

Tags: sharepoint-2013

How to add a specific metadata column to all document libraries created in sharepoint using remote event receivers and provider hosted app.

Comment: first try something, and then ask a question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Vaish - please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Its good to show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Event Receivers are not used to add columns to a document library, it is mainly used to process data and do validations. The word remote here is used since SharePoint 2013 as it was moved outside of SharePoint and SharePoint invokes a remote URL to call the event receiver.

As for your case, you can do that using PowerShell script that can be ran once, provide the site you want and the document library template or none if you want to add the columns to all libraries in the site.

The answer for this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134952/add-columns-to-existing-libraries-in-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell) explains how to add an existing site columnn to a library, you just need to modify it to iterate over all the libraries

Answer (score 0):

I would create a console application to add a column since this seems like a one time job.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 

SP.List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements"); 

SP.Field field = list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field DisplayName='MyField2'     Type='Number' />", 
                                       true, 
                                       AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue); 
SP.FieldNumber fldNumber = context.CastTo<FieldNumber>(field);
fldNumber.MaximumValue = 100; 
fldNumber.MinimumValue = 35; 
fldNumber.Update(); 

context.ExecuteQuery(); 
}
```